# Draw method not drawing anything

Tags: android, drawing

I have a custom view that has a draw method that should draw a red oval that covers the screen but nothing is happening. I checked that my custom view's draw method was being called and it was.

This is the class:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    Paint red = new Paint();
    RectF ovalRec = new RectF(0,0,MainActivity.dUWidth,MainActivity.dUHeight);

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        red.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
    }


    protected  void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.i("log_tag", "DRAWING THE OVAL");
        canvas.drawOval(ovalRec, red);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Here you can see what dUWidth and dUHeight are.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static int dUWidth;
        public static int dUHeight;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Auto-gen code
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Getting height & width of USABLE display and setting it to Point variable.
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point sizeOfDisplay = new Point();
        display.getSize(sizeOfDisplay);
        dUWidth = sizeOfDisplay.x;
        dUHeight = sizeOfDisplay.y;
    }
```

Here is the declaration of it in XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.XXX.targetexercise.CustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> `setContentView()`

-> parse your layout file

-> find your CustomView

-> start to create your CustomView

-> create your `ovalRec`

-> use dUWidth and dUHeight which are 0

-> (out of setContentView but still in onCreate) initialize dUWidth and dUheight

It's not the REAL every steps of the process but I think it's easier to understand that way.

So try to update your `ovalRec` after you initialize dUWidth & dUHeight and call `View.invalidate()`.

Comment: I placed a invalidate() at the end of my draw method so it would be called repeatedly. However the screen is still white. Maybe it is because the view is getting invalidated so fast I can't see the oval?

Comment: You just invalidated repeatly, but the ovelRec was still (0,0,0,0). You have to update the ovelRec and then call invalidate()